# How to test app on device by installing .app (binary) file? (without using Xcode for testing)

Tags: iphone, testing, device, .app

I have created an app and I want to send that to another person for testing it. )

He got an iPhone and a mac, but doesn't have xcode on his mac. (he is not an iphone programmer) So,

**If I send the .app file, can he test that on his iPhone?   If not, how else I can do this?**

This is my first app :) and I have no idea about testing on real devices. So please help me.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do what's called "ad-hoc distribution", which requires creating a special ad-hoc provisioning profile that includes your tester's device UDID.

I highly recommend https://testflight.apple.com/ as it greatly simplifies distributing your ad-hoc builds.

Comment: Wish I could +2 for testflightapp.com -- It's awesome.

Comment: https://www.diawi.com/ can also be used to distribute the app with ease.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what "Ad-hoc" testing is. You'll need to:

1. Add the friend's device to the iOS provisioning portal at developer.apple.com
2. Generate a provisioning profile that includes it for your app.
3. Build the app using this profile.
4. Generate an .IPA file using Product->Archive
5. Send the friend that .IPA file.

Many more details available in Apple's guides under "Ad-Hoc" testing.

Comment: The relevant documentation for this is currently [**Distributing your app to registered devices**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-to-registered-devices), this summary is broadly up to date but skips the part where [the friend actually installs the app on their device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-to-registered-devices#Install-the-app-on-user-devices): they'll need to use either XCode or Apple Configurator.