# Send a newly compiled iPad application to someone

Tags: ipad, deployment, ios4, installation

I'm pretty new to this. I've compiled an iPad application and I want my client to install it on its iPad to test it before putting it in the Apple Store.

I have the UUID of the iPad in question but I don't physically have access to it.

What are the steps involved? After compiling my app, what binaries I have to send to my clients? Is there any signing involved? Hw can he install it on its iPad?

Thanks for your understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://testflightapp.com

Also this recent question: [How to test app on device by installing .app (binary) file? (without using Xcode for testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651357/how-to-test-app-on-device-by-installing-app-binary-file-without-using-xcode/6651400#6651400)